# Edit jar files with python

Tags: java, python, jar

Do you know a python module with which i can add files to a JAR archive?

(what i wan't to do is add .class files to a jar archive)

and the program that has to do it has to be written in python

Thanks!

Comment: .jar files are basically standard .zip files with a different ending, so you should be able to add files using the zipfile module

Answer (score 10, accepted):

.jar files are just .zip files with a different file extension and a manifest.

Try http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) calling the jar command:

```
import subprocess
def add_to_jar(file2add, jar_file):
    cmd = 'jar -uf ' + jar_file + " " + file2add
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)

add_to_jar(file_to_add, jar_file)
```